# Target .NET Core Class Library From .NET Framework 4.6.2 Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-4.6.2

I have a library written using .NET Core, targetting .netstandard2.0. According to this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) it should be compatible to use the that version of a .NET Core library with .NET 4.6.2 and 4.6.1. However, when I try to build my .NET Framework library, I get this error:

> Project 'c:\myproj.csproj' targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to build the libraries. Is what I'm doing not possible/supported and I'm just misinterpreting the information on the website? The .NET Framework library is referencing System.Management.Automation and is a PowerShell Module, but references code in the .NET core library that is being used in other projects as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254288/referencing-a-net-standard-library-from-a-windows-class-library/42364427#42364427

Answer (score 9):

I resolved this issue by placing this in the  tag:

```
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net462</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier Condition="'$(_ShortFrameworkIdentifier)'=='net'">.NETFramework</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier Condition="'$(_ShortFrameworkIdentifier)'=='netstandard'">.NETStandard</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
```

This allowed me to build the .NET Framework class library referencing the .NET core project. Not what I expected from the documentation, since it makes it seem like .netstandard is the new PCL, but it works.

Comment: what "tag" did you put that in? Where is that?

Comment: @mcmillab In the csproj file undedr <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"><PropertyGroup>. You should see an existing TargetFramework in the xml.

Comment: @mhakan thanks that worked. For others just to be clear this is in the csproj file for the dotnetCore library, and it replaces the existing TargetFrameworks line.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, VS 2017 does not directly support daily builds / preview 2.0 tooling. The SDK that is included with VS 2017 (15.0,15.1) doesn't know about netstandard 2.0 and neither does the integrated NuGet extension.

See https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/231 for a few workarounds to use preview tooling in the currently released VS 2017 versions.

Comment: I had the same issues targetting netstandard1.6 and netstandard1.5 as well, so I don't think this was necessarily specific to 2.0. I tried with the class library targeting 1.6 and got Project 'C:\myproj.csproj' targets '.NETStandard,Version=v1.6'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.

Comment: This is because 4.6.2 doesn't support 1.6 libraries using the released tooling (1.0.*)

Comment: Had the same result with .netstandard1.5, which the website says is supported with 4.6.2.